# How to add Delete , Share , Cancel button on longpress?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to coding, now creating an android app which has some videos under video tab/list, and my question is how can I add a Delete(with a notification), Share, Cancel button when I long press a specific video which I want to delete (from internal storage)? Guide me with examples. In totally new into this :)

minSdkVersion="11"
targetSdkVersion="25"

Searched in but didn't find any appropriate answer with examples, though ..

Eager to study :(

```js
@Override

public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
      switch(item.getItemId()) {
         case R.id.deletevideo:
         // add stuff here
            return true;
          case R.id.sharevideo:
            // edit stuff here
                return true;
          case R.id.cancelvideo:
        // remove stuff here
                return true;K
          default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
      }
}
}
```

```html
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    <item
        android:id="@+id/deletevideo"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:title="@string/video_delete"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/sharevideo"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
        android:title="@string/video_share"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/cancelvideo"
        android:title="@string/video_Cancel"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: Please follow below references http://www.vogella.com/tutorials then you can start coding.

Comment: i will check it bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is add contextListener:

Java File

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
      super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

          MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
          inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_list, menu);
          return true;


}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
      switch(item.getItemId()) {
         case R.id.add:
         // add stuff here
            return true;
          case R.id.edit:
            // edit stuff here
                return true;
          case R.id.delete:
        // remove stuff here
                return true;
          default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
      }
}
```

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

       <item android:id="@+id/add"
              android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
              android:title="@string/menu_delete" />

      <item android:id="@+id/edit"
              android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
              android:title="@string/menu_share" />

       <item android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/my_icon_delete"
             android:title="@string/menu_cancle" />

</menu>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134079/discussion-on-answer-by-hiren-jungi-how-to-add-delete-share-cancel-button-on).